# htaccess rewrite: Grab text after last slash as parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to rewrite this

> www.domain.com/123

to this

> www.domain.com/index.php?p=123

Which works fine.

However, I need to be able to insert some keywords for SEO-purposes in front of the technical parameter, so the visible URL would look like this:

> www.domain.com/a/b/c/123

and I still only need the text after the very last slash (or, if there is a trailing slash, between the last two slashes tbe.)

I suppose this has been answered before but I can't find it...

Thanks
Raphael

Comment: IS it always the case that last part is a number?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it's an invalid parameter value

Comment: ok good then @Croise's answer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Lines with -d and -f are not required. This is just in case you use folders or files with just numbers names. This is rarely the case...